# Python: For defaultdict, print keys and values

Tags: python, defaultdict

This dictionary keeps on changing with keys and values. So, I want to access these keys and values and print it like expected answer. As I am new to Python, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
     dictionary=
       {'key1': {'key10': [[66619, 'event1'], [64800, 'event2']]},
        'key2': {'key11': [[28250, 'event3'], [17960, 'event4'], [23484, 'event5'], [21945, 'event6']]},
        'key3': {'key12': [[359319, 'event7'], [322334, 'event8'], [273316, 'event9']], 'key13': [[452945, 'event10'], [414268, 'event11']]}
       }
```

Expected answer:

Name:key1 , Address:key10, Number:66619, Pin_code:event1

Name:key1 , Address:key10, Number:64800, Pin_code:event2

Name:key2 , Address:key11, Number:28250, Pin_code:event3

Name:key2 , Address:key11, Number:17960, Pin_code:event4

Name:key2 , Address:key11, Number:23484, Pin_code:event5

Name:key2 , Address:key11, Number:21945, Pin_code:event6

Name:key3 , Address:key12, Number:359319, Pin_code:event7

Name:key3 , Address:key12, Number:322334, Pin_code:event8

Name:key3 , Address:key12, Number:273316, Pin_code:event9

Name:key3 , Address:key13, Number:452945, Pin_code:event10

Name:key3 , Address:key13, Number:414268, Pin_code:event11

Comment: where is the reference to "defaultdict"

Comment: this could interest you: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary are unordered in nature. You have to use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to maintain the order within `dict`. As per the [`OrderedDict` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
>   methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

If you just want to print this content without actually storing the sorted data, you may do it with simple `sorted()` function as:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
    for k1, v1 in sorted(v.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
        for content in v1:
            print 'Name: {}, Address: {}, Number: {}, Pin: {}'.format(k, k1, content[0], content[1])
```

which will print:

```
Name: key1, Address: key10, Number: 66619, Pin: event1
Name: key1, Address: key10, Number: 64800, Pin: event2
Name: key2, Address: key11, Number: 28250, Pin: event3
Name: key2, Address: key11, Number: 17960, Pin: event4
Name: key2, Address: key11, Number: 23484, Pin: event5
Name: key2, Address: key11, Number: 21945, Pin: event6
Name: key3, Address: key12, Number: 359319, Pin: event7
Name: key3, Address: key12, Number: 322334, Pin: event8
Name: key3, Address: key12, Number: 273316, Pin: event9
Name: key3, Address: key13, Number: 452945, Pin: event10
Name: key3, Address: key13, Number: 414268, Pin: event11
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name itemgetter

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is `from operator import itemgetter`

Comment: Thank you very much. That's really working